# What is the best way to abstract out common api types in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have 10+ search requests with common request fields that may be abstracted. For example, 2 fields are common across them all similar to the following:

For a common search

```
{ 
  name: 'purple',
  guid: '1672d0cf-08dc-4c04-9ce2-a2e6e85d1d13',
  searchType: 'common'  
}
```

For details on a visit

```
{ 
  name: 'purple',
  guid: '1672d0cf-08dc-4c04-9ce2-a2e6e85d1d13',
  visitId: 35
}
```

It would be nice to do something like the following in something like **APISearch.ts**

```
    import { search } from './APIModels.ts'

    export class commonSearch extends search {
      public searchType?: string;
    }

    export class visitRequestSearch extends search {
      public visitId: number;
    }
```

**APIModals.ts**

```
    export class search {
      public name?: string;
      public guid?: string;
    }
```

I get the following ERROR when I try to include my base search

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
[at-loader] src\app\ApiModels.ts:12:44
    TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.
```

My fiddler seems to think the abstraction if reasonable : https://jsfiddle.net/michael_shomsky/0bppt8dg/2/

So why would I get an error.  I started looking at some of the documentation again (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) it appears like I should be using some kind of intersection, but I'm looking to have a library of available search requests, not a factory; so possibly there is another pattern or I messed up somewhere.

Comment: On your `fiddler` your `stringIt()` function signature is wrong. You need to use `public stringIt(): string {...}`

Comment: Thanks.  I updated the method to debug(), but neglected to update the link version. https://jsfiddle.net/michael_shomsky/0bppt8dg/2/ has the debug():any method and https://jsfiddle.net/michael_shomsky/0bppt8dg/3 takes your comment and commits it to return a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fooling around with various ways of doing this I realize now there was a mistake in how the file is imported.  So apparently `TS2507: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.` is a response to a missing super class (well, at least it was in my case).:

The following import got the ".ts" removed and began working as expected (similar to the JSFiddle)

```
import { search } from './APIModels.ts';
```

needed to be

```
import { search } from './APIModels';
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, it seems you should be using Typescript interface instead. Something along the line of:

```
interface BaseRequest {
    name: string,
    guid: string
}

interface CommonSearch extends BaseRequest {
    searchType: string
}

interface VisitDetail extends BaseRequest {
    visitId: number
}
```

Comment: I agree, however where I work currently it was requested that we follow that pattern; however, when committing the idea to non-full-stack (backend-only) devs, it became confusing to them and was rejected (with disregard for https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html ).  Without going into too much detail, even though typescript would like it this way, back-end developers couldn't acquiesce to the notion that an interface could be a JSON schema.